# How to get redirect URL in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app that shows an image taken from source.unsplash. My request url is:

```
https://source.unsplash.com/random/`$widthx$height`
```

Then the service redirects to some specific image url picked fitting my width and height.

I can show the image with:
`Image.network(url above)`,
but I cannot access the new redirected url for some other parts of my code which is really necessary. Is there a way to get it?

Thanks in advance

Something I'm searching for is like

```
Http.Response response = await Http.get(url);
print(response.finalRedirectURL);
```

Comment: you need to provide more code

Comment: I've tried many ways using Dart.io, http.dart and some packages from pub.
However, I didn't find any solution so now my code is as simple as:
Image.network(the url above).

Comment: you need to show more of your working code. just pasting a url is not helpful for those who wanna help you.

Comment: The question doesn't need my working code even if there were some.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be better if you use api.unsplash.com and not source.

If `followRedirects` is true, there's no way according to the docs to get the final redirected URL, so maybe post a github issue for this. See: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html

The only way I see this happening is making `followRedirects: false`, will give you a response headers with `location` as a key that gives you the next redirect. You'd have to write a loop to keep going till the status code changes from 302 to something else.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For my own project, I was also not able to find any method from flutter/dart side.

However, I was able to find the `location` in `response.headers`. Maybe this can work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
  Future<String?> getUrlLocation(String url) async {
    final client = HttpClient();
    var uri = Uri.parse(url);
    var request = await client.getUrl(uri);
    request.followRedirects = false;
    var response = await request.close();
    return response.headers.value(HttpHeaders.locationHeader);
  }
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is when I try find the redirected URL for links like https://link.medium.com/VAXEz2Rg3vb it fails to provide me with a relevant browsable link.